# What is missing from this code?

Tags: bash

I keep getting error (`` lab2.sh: line 7: syntax error at line 15: `)' unexpected ``)

```
#! /bin/sh

echo "M - Month of the year"

echo "S - Sleep for 10 seconds"

echo "E - Make the file executable"
echo "Please input a letter (M,S, or E): \c"

read code

case $code in

     M) date +%B ;;
     S)  sleep 10 ;;
     E) echo "ENter file name: \c"
      read fname
      chmod 755 $fname
     *)   
 echo "Error" ;;

esac
```

Comment: You forgot to use `;;` after the commands in case `E)`.

Comment: you can easily catch such issues yourself by using http://www.shellcheck.net/ ... also, note that you should `/bin/bash` and not `/bin/sh`

Answer (score 5):

Every set of commands following a pattern in `case ... esac` needs to be terminated by `;;`, except for the last one.

You should have

```
M)  date +%B ;;
S)  sleep 10 ;;
E)  echo "ENter file name: \c"
    read fname
    chmod 755 "$fname" ;;
*)  echo "Error" >&2
```

Also note the quoting of `$fname` (so that you can handle file names with spaces and special characters), and that diagnostic messages should go to standard error (redirecting to `>&2`).

---

You could also use `select` for your menu, and be a bit more careful when running `chmod` on the file:

```
#!/bin/bash

select ch in \
    'Exit' \
    'Month of the year' \
    'Sleep for 10 seconds' \
    'Make a file executable'
do
    case $REPLY in
        1) break ;;
        2) date +'The current month is %B' ;;
        3) echo 'Sleeping for 10 seconds'
           sleep 10 ;;
        4) read -r -p 'Enter file name: ' fname
           if [ ! -f "$fname" ]; then
               printf 'No such file: %s\n' "$fname"
           else
               chmod +x "$fname"
           fi
           ;;
        *) echo 'Error' >&2
    esac
done

echo 'Bye!'
```